# SSDT Compare operation with SQLCmd variables in SQL Project

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-data-tools, sqlcmd

SSDT Compare I have just found does not recongize it's own SQLCMD variables.

I have a SSDT SQL Project that I deploy to a DEV database.

I want to compare the SSDT SQL Project to the DEV database after deploy.

The problem is the SQLCMD variables in the project get flagged as differences by the compare engine.

WTH?  This is a serious DEFECT and LIMITATION Microsoft has apparently not rectified in many years.

Am I missing something or is this just really bad?

Comment: Are the default values for the variables set in project properties?

Comment: Yes, that is all setup.  The publish operation works just fine.  It's only the compare that has issues.  I am starting to think this is expected behavior.  Try it out to see if you can compare a database with a sql project or dacpac.  The issue only arises with external db references and sqlcmd variables.